# millisecond at which a key or a mouse stroke is pressed in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently I have two functions which do this :-

```
        protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs a)
        {
            base.OnInitialized(a);
            var timer4 = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer4.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
            timer4.Tick += (s, e) => Main.EventMouseTimer();
            timer4.Tick += (s, e) => Gauge.Text = Main.EnergyGauge;
            timer4.Start();
        }
```

```
        public void EventMouseTimer()
        {
            String DateToday = DateTime.Today.ToShortTimeString();
            String TimeToday = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
            float TimeNow = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

            //before your loop
            var csv = new StringBuilder();

            //in your loop
            var mouse = MouseButtons.Left.ToString();
            var Date = DateToday.ToString();
            var Time = TimeToday.ToString();
            var Milliseconds = TimeNow.ToString();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                var newLine = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", mouse, Date, Time, Milliseconds);
                csv.AppendLine(newLine);
                //after your loop
                string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                string filename = "Temp";
                string FileName = Path.Combine(path, filename + ".txt");
                File.WriteAllText(FileName, csv.ToString());
            }
        }
```

This doesn't seem to be working. How can I capture the exact millisecond when a key is pressed?

Comment: By an event.... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/input-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 This page has everything you need to know about input in WPF

Comment: I find a comment that reads `//after your loop` to be in a loop highly confusing.

Comment: Don't set a timer to fire every millisecond. There isn't enough processing going to happen in a millisecond to do almost anything.   It's not practical to find the exact millisecond a key was pressed.  Eg  the time will vary from one pc to another. Pressing a key physically to a key press event will not be instant. Why would you even care between one millisecond and the next when they type "g"?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ The General. This solved the issue.